# How do i prevent a transparant image from repeating while exporting?

Tags: node-editor, export, image, gltf

I am trying to export this 3D-laptop as a gltf-file. The model contains a png-image, see below:

[image: This is the model I try to export, it contains a png-image]

I applied these nodes to make the png-image transparant on the laptops surface:

[image: I applied these nodes to make the png-image transparant]

This are my export settings:

[image: This are my export settings]

However, when I export the model, it comes out like this:

[image: However, when I export the model, it comes out like this.]

As you can see, none of the nodes are applied while exporting as a glb-file. The png-image is not transparant anymore and it is repeated. I don't know why this is the case. May you please help me?

Comment: This sounds like https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/1113, which was fixed in Blender 2.90. Are you using a recent version of Blender? If so, and it's still not working, you may need to file a new issue there with the `.blend` file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DonMcCurdy. I'm using the most recent version of blender. I'll look into it and eventually make the issue. Thanks for your time and help! :)